# AlertDialog in onClick crashes on second click

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the below code, which disabled an AlertDialog when a EditText field is clicked. This works perfectly the first time, however if the user closes the Dialog and then clicks the field again the app crashes.

```
roomnumberPicker = new MaterialNumberPicker.Builder(SearchActivity.this)
                .minValue(1)
                .maxValue(15)
                .defaultValue(1)
                .textSize(20)
                .enableFocusability(false)
                .wrapSelectorWheel(true)
                .build();

        roomEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this)
                        .setView(roomnumberPicker)
                        .setTitle("Pick number of Rooms:")
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                roomEdit.setText(Integer.toString(roomnumberPicker.getValue()));
                            }
                        }).show();

            }
        });
```

Which errors:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] Make the roomnumberPicker final. You will be able to access it.

Your MaterialNumberPicker is attached to its parent for the first time. So second time onwards when you are trying to add that again to a new AlertDialog its throwing you that exception.

Try this:

```
roomEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final MaterialNumberPicker roomnumberPicker = new MaterialNumberPicker.Builder(SearchActivity.this)
            .minValue(1)
            .maxValue(15)
            .defaultValue(1)
            .textSize(20)
            .enableFocusability(false)
            .wrapSelectorWheel(true)
            .build();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this)
                .setView(roomnumberPicker)
                .setTitle("Pick number of Rooms:")
                .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        roomEdit.setText(Integer.toString(roomnumberPicker.getValue()));
                    }
                }).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: `roomnumberPicker.getValue()` does not work as roomnumberPicker is accessed from an inner class